# What are some good mathematical journals?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I would like to study mathematics when I'm older, but I want to read some of the current literature to learn what mathematics is truly about, maybe direct my studies into some particular field. What would be some good mathematical journals that I could read to have a general idea of the current situation of mathematics?

Comment: The American Mathematical Society may have some journals or magazines

Comment: Most math journals are meant for people who have already studied mathematics.

Comment: There aren't any, at least in English.  American Mathematical Monthly has the occasional high quality survey article.

Comment: Journals are the wrong direction to go to get overviews of modern mathematics. It might even be better to browse Wikipedia and some blogs. You essentially have one problem, but you've restricted your solution unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the Fibonacci Quarterly.

I also like the MAA's 
magazines:
American Mathematical Monthly,
Mathematics Magazine,
and
College Mathematics Journal.

If you have access to 
a university library,
it can be fun to
go into the stacks
and look at old math journals.
I remember years ago
enjoyably
browsing through the
Journal of the London Mathematical Society.